# Android Billing test purchase id deprecated?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-instrumentation, android-billing, play-billing-library

I used test puchase ids such as "android.test.purchased" for my instrumentation tests. When I last run these tests they failed on every device, as the dialog does not show any "Purchase button". When I use the real ids it's working as expected.

[The reference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test) does not list these ids anymore and I could not find an official page where they appear. But neither I could find an article where they state that the ids are deprecated.

Does anybody know if they are deprecated or if this is just a bug in the newest version of billing library?

I'd like to use test ids rather than real ones, because otherwise I'm spammed with mails. And more important because I sometimes use a real account that is not in the list of testers on the same device. If I forget to switch back to the test account, I will be charged for every test (of course the money returns back to me, but the fees and taxes will be charged for real).

That's how the dialog looks lately, when I use test ids:
[image: Dialog with test purchase ID]